# Samsung S21 where is enable auto space after period setting

Tags: keyboard

I cannot find the setting for auto space after period when I'm typing a message on my Samsung S21.

Anybody knows where it is?

**hope it's not part of the autocorrect, because I have that turned off, because it's making a mess in my language*

Comment: Which keyboard app you are using? Look into its settings. Go into Settings app -> System / Language & Input > Virtual  keyboard -> your keyboard app -> look for the setting you are after.

Comment: The feature and its setting depends on the keyboard app. I don't know if Samsung Keyboard has it, though I know Gboard has this.

Comment: I use Samsung keyboard

Comment: @Firelord: thats the first place I looked, but it's not there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samsung keyboard does not have that option to add a space after a full stop. It has an opposite option instead which adds a full stop before two spaces, converting one of the spaces after a word to a full stop.

- Bring up the keyboard,
- tap the keyboard input method chooser in the bottom right,
- select the "cog" and it will bring up the keyboard settings.
- A short way down there is the "More typing options". Tap that.
- in there you will find an option "double tap space bar to add full stop"